# Regex pattern not matching for the recipes of a target rule in the following Makefile:

Tags: c++, regex, unix, makefile

```
edit : main.o kbd.o command.o display.o \
       insert.o search.o files.o utils.o
        cc -o edit main.o kbd.o command.o display.o \
                   insert.o search.o files.o utils.o
```

this is my Makefile, I want to extract the target, multi-line dependencies and multi-line recipes using regex patterns, but I am only able to extract two groups from the first line
i.e., `edit`  and `main.o kbd.o command.o display.o \`

I wrote a c++ code to check and print out the target, recipes and dependencies:

A struct for holding the rule name, dependency list and recipe list

```
struct TargetRule {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::string> dependencies;
    std::string recipe;
};
```

function to split the dependency list

```
std::vector<std::string> splitDependencies(const std::string& dependencies) {
    std::vector<std::string> dependencyVector;
    std::istringstream iss(dependencies);
    std::string dependency;
    while (iss >> dependency) {
        dependencyVector.push_back(dependency);
    }
    return dependencyVector;
}
```

function to check if it's the beginning of the recipe line to extract all recipes

```
bool isRecipeLine(const std::string& line, bool isLastDependencyLine) {
    return isLastDependencyLine && !line.empty() && line[0] == '\t';
}
```

process the input file, line by line by matching the regex pattern and separate the recipes, dependencies and target rule names

```
 int main() {
        std::ifstream file(R"(C:\Users\user\Desktop\Makefile.mk)");
        const std::regex basicRuleRegex(
                "^([^:\\s]+)\\s*:"                        // Target (Group 1)
                "(.*(?:\\s\\\\\\n)*)\\s*"                // Dependencies (Group 2)
                             
            "^([\\t ]+(.*))"                         // Recipe (Group 3)
    );

    std::string line;
    TargetRule currentRule;

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening the file!" << std::endl;
        return 1; // Return error code 1
    }

    bool isDependencyLine = false;
    bool isLastDependencyLine = false; // Flag to indicate if the current line is the last dependency line
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        std::smatch match;
        if (std::regex_match(line, match, basicRuleRegex)) {

            if (!currentRule.name.empty()) {
                // Output previous rule
                std::cout << "Target: " << currentRule.name << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Dependencies:" << std::endl;
                for (const auto& dep : currentRule.dependencies) {
                    std::cout << "\t" << dep << std::endl;
                }
                std::cout << "Recipe:" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "\t" << currentRule.recipe << std::endl;
                std::cout << std::endl;

                // Clear current rule
                currentRule = TargetRule();
            }

            // Extract new rule
            currentRule.name = match[1];
            if(!isLastDependencyLine) {
                std::string dependencies = match[2];

                // Handle multi-line dependencies
                while (dependencies.back() == '\\') {
                    std::string nextLine;
                    if (std::getline(file, nextLine)) {
                        dependencies.pop_back(); // Remove backslash
                        dependencies += nextLine;
                    } else {
                        isLastDependencyLine = true;
                        break; // No more lines in file
                    }
                }
                currentRule.dependencies = splitDependencies(dependencies);
                isLastDependencyLine = true;

            }
            // Extract recipe
            currentRule.recipe = match[3];
            if (currentRule.recipe.empty()) {
                // If recipe is not captured, continue reading lines until we find the recipe or reach the end of file
                while (std::getline(file, line)) {
                    if (isRecipeLine(line, isLastDependencyLine)) {
                        // Found the recipe, append it to the current rule's recipe
                        currentRule.recipe += line.substr(1); // Remove leading tab
                        break;
                    }
                    // Check if the current line is the last dependency line
                    isLastDependencyLine = !line.empty() && line.back() == '\\';
                }
            }
        } else if (!isDependencyLine) {
            // If it's not a dependency line, set the flag accordingly
            isDependencyLine = true;
        } else {
            // It's a dependency line, reset the flag accordingly
            isLastDependencyLine = !line.empty() && line.back() == '\\';
            isDependencyLine = false;
        }
    }

    // Output the last rule
    if (!currentRule.name.empty()) {
        std::cout << "Target: " << currentRule.name << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Dependencies:" << std::endl;
        for (const auto& dep : currentRule.dependencies) {
            std::cout << "\t" << dep << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Recipe:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\t" << currentRule.recipe << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Target: edit
Dependencies:
        main.o
        kbd.o
        command.o
        display.o
        insert.o
        search.o
        files.o
        utils.o
Recipe:
```

Comment: If I am understanding this right the problem is the lines ending in backslashes don't work because they don't match your regexes. I suggest you replace `std::getline(file, line)` with a call to a function which reads a line form the file, but repeats and concatentates if that line ends with a backslash. In other words remove process the backslashes before you hand the line off to your regexes.

Comment: The point of @john's comment is to see if the backslash is the issue, regardless of whether you like to see them there or not.

Comment: if I do that, it will be a trouble to separate recipes and dependencies, because they are almost the same, the only difference that separates them both is the last line of dependency does not end with a backslash \ and the immediate next line (beginning of the recipe line) starts with a tab space and they can also be in multiple lines until the next target name appears, where the new target rule name is definitely followed by a colon :, you can see this for more reference:
[official gnu make utility reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Simple-Makefile) @john

Comment: Not at all, @Novice.  The essential difference between target lines and recipe lines is that the latter each start with at least one tab character.  That's how `make` itself recognizes them (after line-continuation processing).

Comment: I think that's what I said, a new recipe line starts with a tab space when the multi-line dependencies end @JohnBollinger

Comment: So what's the problem?  Performing line-continuation processing does not make trouble for you.  Quite the opposite: it makes your job easier.  After such processing is performed, you can tell immediately and easily whether the resulting logical line is a recipe line: it is one if and only if its first character is a tab.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think that the rest of dependency lines for a target rule also starts with a tab, then to separate them from recipe lines is to continue consuming them until you don't see a backslash in the current line and you see a tab space in the next line (beginning of a new recipe line). do you have any approaches to match them and separate them into groups of dependencies and recipes?

Comment: Re.`"I think that the rest of dependency lines for a target rule also starts with a tab,"`: if you process the backslash characters (as suggested in the comments above) there *is* only one dependency line.  By way of an exercise, take the makefile in your question, replace each backslash/space/newline sequence with a single space and think about how you would process the result.

Comment: Makefile rules consist of exactly *one* (logical) line expressing targets and their dependencies, optionally followed by one or more tab-indented (logical) lines of recipe.  Again, that leading tab is how `make` itself distinguishes between them.  Processing the line continuations gets you from physical lines to the logical lines on which that criterion depends.

Comment: @Novice I read the gnu reference, and you are correct, my idea of preprocessing the backslashes does not work, because backslashes in recipe lines are treated differently, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Splitting-Recipe-Lines).

Comment: My recommendation is that you invoke `make -p` and parse the output of that, rather than trying to parse the makefile itself.  This will allow make itself to handle all the backslash-newline behaviors for target definition lines.